# How to download a file from Google Drive using the Camel Google-Drive Component?

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-camel

How to download a file from Google Drive using the Camel Google-Drive component?

Using the URI `google-drive://drive-files/get?fileId=validfileID12345` results in only the metadata of the specified file.

How would I use the Google Drive component to download the file and pass it to the next component in the route?

Comment: Workaround: Using the `GoogleDriveFilesConverter.download(metadata, exchange)` function to download the files content using it's downloadURL. If a file doesn't have a a downloadURL, write your own function that uses one of the exportLinks from the metadata (Use sourcecode of `GoogleDriveFilesConverter.download()` as example).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `alt=media` to the URL. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get for details

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunatly the Camel Google-drive component cannot resolve the parameter `alt=media`